# Post Image on Twitter Using Fabric via Card

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I need to upload image and status using fabric.

The status is successfully updated but Image not Uploaded

Below is the Code:

```
 final Card card = new Card.AppCardBuilder(TwitterActivity.this)
                        .imageUri(uriToUpload)
                        .iPhoneId("123456")
                        .iPadId("123456")
                        .build();
                final Intent intent = new ComposerActivity.Builder(TwitterActivity.this)
                        .session(session)
                        .card(card)
                        .hashtags("#fabric1", "#twitter1")
                        .createIntent();
                startActivity(intent);
```

But it give following error:

```
Post Tweet failed
                                                                       com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException: HTTP request failed, Status: 403
                                                                           at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback.onResponse(Callback.java:42)
                                                                           at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```